# How to build a condition based on a composite data type with jOOQ?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

In my view I have a column that refers to another table as its data type:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT c.*, CAST(p.* AS parent) AS entity_parent
FROM entity_child c
LEFT JOIN parent p ON c.parent_id = p.id
GROUP BY c.id, p.id;
```

I need to query the view based on a value of the entity/parent value. With PostgreSQL it looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_view
WHERE (entity_parent).secret_value = 42;
```

jOOQ nows the correct data type of entity_parent (ParentRecord), but I failed to translate my query.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jOOQ API currently doesn't allow for generating UDT element dereferencing expressions out of the box. The relevant feature request is this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/228

However, as always, you can easily work around such a limitation in the jOOQ API by using the plain SQL templating API:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating

```java
public static <T, U extends UDTRecord> Field<T> dereference(
    Field<? extends U> parent, 
    UDTField<U, T> child
) {
    return DSL.field("({0}).{1}", child.getDataType(), parent, child.getUnqualifiedName());
}
```

And then, use it as follows:

```java
ctx.selectFrom(MY_VIEW)
   .where(dereference(MY_VIEW.ENTITY_PARENT, Parent.SECRET_VALUE).eq(42))
   .fetch();
```

Comment: Finally, I discarded the use Postgre's cast function, selected all fields and mapped them by myself. I recognised that jOOQ was able to identify `enitity_parent` as a ParentRecord, but when I executed an query, it tried to cast an PGObject to ParentRecord, which failed.